project rotated tikz-3dplot object onto plane
I have drawn an object in tikz using the tikz-3dplot syntax \setrotatedcoords{<angle>}{<angle>}{<angle>}. I want to find the path of its projection onto the xy-plane.
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\foreach \Vt in {-5,-4,...,5}{
\draw[ultra thin] (\Vt,-5) -- (\Vt,5);
\draw[ultra thin] (-5,\Vt) -- (5,\Vt);}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{80}{30}{0}

% I want the projection of this on the xy-plane:
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords,red,ultra thick,variable=\Vt,domain=0:360,smooth] plot ({cos(\Vt)},{sin(\Vt)},0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit
To elaborate a bit, I want to draw the projections of something like this (sorry if it's a bit silly):

Similar to this:


Your \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords... does exactly that. To be able to draw the path, it calculates what the path is like in the canvas cs. I guess you want an other way to do the same thing!? It would help to know why? What do you need it for - it is easier to help solve a specific problem.

@hpekristiansen The goal behind this is to draw an object and its projections on the planes. I'll post a picture I've drawn so you can see what I mean.

I do not know if there is a better way - I am only able to do it point wise. To connect the points smoothly, you can use the hobby package and the hobby shortcut .. instead of --.
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, thick]
\foreach \Vt in {-5,-4,...,5}{
\draw[ultra thin] (\Vt,-5) -- (\Vt,5);
\draw[ultra thin] (-5,\Vt) -- (5,\Vt);}

\draw[red, ->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0); 
\draw[green, ->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0); 
\draw[blue, ->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{80}{30}{0}
\draw[red, densely dotted, ->, tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0); 
\draw[green, densely dotted, ->, tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0); 
\draw[blue, densely dotted, ->, tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);

%original circle
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords, red, ultra thick, variable=\Vt, domain=0:360, smooth] plot ({cos(\Vt)},{sin(\Vt)},0);
         
%same circle with points
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords] ({cos(0)},{sin(0)},0) foreach \t in {10,20,...,350}{-- ({cos(\t)},{sin(\t)},0) -- ({cos(\t+10)},{sin(\t+10)},0)};

%projection of these points on main xy plane
\draw
 \pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{cos(0)}{sin(0)}{0}} (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)
 foreach \t in {10,20,...,350}{ 
 \pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{cos(\t)}{sin(\t)}{0}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0) 
 \pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{cos(\t+10)}{sin(\t+10)}{0}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



'only' :-) ....
